# Find a linear operator which operates on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a linear operator that operates on polynomials with a degree less or equal to 2 such that $f(P) = 2 P'$, where $P'$ is a derivative. What is the matrix of this operator in a basis $1, x, x^2$

---

Here is my approach:

Let $c + bx + ax^2$ is the polynomial, so its derivative is $b + 2ax$. So I can write the problem in the following way:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
c & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & b & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix} \cdot X = \begin{pmatrix}
2b & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 4a & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

which means that 
$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
2b/c & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 4a/b & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect; you moved the columns from where they should be

Comment: Also, you're multiplying by $X$ from the right, which is not what is normally done here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider $2P'$ as an operator on $P$. It maps $1 \mapsto 2 \cdot 1' = 0$ it maps $x \mapsto 2 \cdot x' = 2$ and maps $x^2 \mapsto 2 \cdot (x^2)' = 4x$. So the matrix for $f$ is: $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 4\\ 0& 0& 0\end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not. The matrix should be independent of $a,b$ and $c$.

---

Hint:
Look at the definition of the matrix for the operator again and calculate
$$
f(1), \quad f(x), \quad f(x^2). 
$$